# Add Bubble view dynamically

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

[image]

Hi guys, I have to achieve the above design. Here no of bubbles are dynamic (maximum 8) and also the size of each bubble is dynamic. I have designed the bubbles dynamically but I can't find out any way to add the bubbles (I mean in which position, which bubble) so that the output will be looks like above.

Bubble will formed randomly each and every times like for 2 bubbles

[image]

for 4 bubbles

[image]

But there is no particular logic that all time for 2 and 4 bubbles position will be same.

To be very honest I am far away to start cause I couldn't figure out the logic. Any idea, any help would be appreciable. Thank you.

Comment: you may want to clarify what the exec t problem is you are facing. Is it how to position, how to draw, how to ?

Comment: not clear question. where is the question ? you are telling us what you have achieved :)

Comment: Guys please check my updated question. I am sorry for that. I am confused about the position

Comment: is this the design what you are trying to achieve or the bubbles should be formed randomly every time. I think you need to explain more in your question.

Comment: It's just a sample design, bubble will formed randomly every time.

Comment: Still I am there, help me guys.

Answer (score 1):

Do:

- create class method for set the frames
- prepare the layout about how they will display. That will be depend on the No of bubbles.

  for ex:
- If 1 bubble than show it in center screen
- If 2 bubbles than show both in 1 line
- If 3 bubbles than make it round display
- if 4 bubble than square display
- If 5 bubbles than shape that you shown image here above

so similarly define frames for all buttons by checking No of bubbles. After that you'll just need to use that class into you code. It will automatically take the frames as you defined in that class.

Comment: It's not an image. It's `UIView`. My problem is in positioning the bubble view

Comment: client will not provide neither coordinates nor frame size. I have to do this.

Comment: @TapasPal than how it'll be dynamic

Comment: There where I am hanging. I knew the frame size only not the coordinates. :(

Comment: @TapasPal ok so its not necessary to make a specific option in centre. There can be any option we can keep in center right ?

Comment: You said Maximum 8 & what about the Minimum ?